# How to open a small window of microsoft edge by command line

Tags: command-line, microsoft-edge

I want open a small Edge's window(i.e 600px*600px) via command line prompt.
So I tried this command, but didn't open small window.
These options aren't supported now?

```
start msedge.exe --new-window --window-size=600,600 https://yahoo.com
```

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer below? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the command line works if you kill all the Edge process in Task Manager first.

You can try to kill all Edge process in Task Manager or run this command line first: `taskkill /F /IM msedge.exe`. After that, you can run your command line then the Edge window will be 600*600.